# From Arrays to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following methods that I wrote are array and boolean methods. I was wondering how, if possible, can I convert the array method into an ArrayList one.

```
public int[] letsMap(){

    int[] iArray = new int[maxBagSize + 1];

    int w;

    for(int i = 0; i < ourBags.size(); i++){
        w = ourBags.get(i).foo;
        iArray[w]++;
    }

    return iArray;

}
```

.

```
public boolean comp(SearchState search){
            boolean cool = false;

            if(search.unBaggedItems.equals(this.unBaggedItems)){
                int[] mine = letsMap();
                int[] theirs = search.letsMap();

                cool= true;

                for(int i = 0; i < maxBagSize; i++){
                    if(mine[i] != theirs[i]){
                        cool = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return cool;
        }
```

Comment: Converted the int[] to ArrayList<>() but got lost in terms of knowing what to do with  iArray[w]++;

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do?  If any of your elements in `ourBags` meets or exceeds the length of the array, you'll get a runtime exception.  Also, what does your method `comp` have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

For the first method:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> letsMap(){

    ArrayList<Integer> iArray = new ArrayList<>(maxBagSize + 1);

    int w;

    for(int i = 0; i < ourBags.size(); i++){
        w = ourBags.get(i).foo;
        iArray.set(w, iArray.get(w) + 1);
    }

    return iArray;

}
```

And for the second:

```
public boolean comp(SearchState search){
    boolean cool = false;

    if(search.unBaggedItems.equals(this.unBaggedItems)){
        ArrayList<Integer> mine = letsMap();
        ArrayList<Integer> theirs = search.letsMap();

        cool = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < maxBagSize; i++){
             if(mine.get(i).compareTo(theirs.get(i)) != 0){
                cool = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return cool;
}
```